# Deploy Android chat server online

Tags: java, android, sockets, webserver, chat

I have created a Simple **socket based chat** application for android devices in which multiple android emulators connect to a server running on local machine. The server has a ip address and is running on some port. It works fine. Now i want to deploy this **server online** to make it visibile to the users. How can i deploy the server online so that user can connect it through some ip and port?

Comment: hmmmm? this is not an android question. Also, you haven't provided any information about how you are deploying your application on the local server. Also, what application server are you using?

Comment: on local machine i have my java programme running that is listening on specify port on which the android clients can connect. I haven't used any server like TomCat or anything.

Comment: When you say "server online" does it mean Internet or your local network Intranet? 
Because there a big difference between them. For Internet you need to know your Public IP address given by your ISP and, for Intranet, you only need your private IP like `192.168.X.XXX`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. On internet i meant.